# Did Einstein's brain weigh less than the average?

Tags: biology, physiology, albert-einstein

Many web-sites claim that Einstein's brain was smaller than average. For example, in [this 2005 phys.org article](https://phys.org/news/2005-01-einsteins-brain.html#jCp):

> Einstein’s brain weighed only 1,230 grams, less than the average adult
>   brain which weighs about 1,400 grams.

However, this figure was measured [after his death](http://www.theilluminerdy.com/2016/03/16/emergency-gaming-kit-einsteins-brain/)  when he was [76 years old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein), and brains [shrink with age](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2596698/).

Is 1,230 grams less than the weight of the average 76-year-old's brain?

Comment: @Lerner Don't your sources answer the question?

Comment: Paywalled but Indeed relevant: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8072950

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's below average for men his age:

> Einstein's brain weight was 1230 g, which is within the average range, but below the mean, for men of his age [[11](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6893659), [14](http://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/142510)].
>   <sub>[Alterations in cortical thickness and neuronal density
>   in the frontal cortex of Albert Einstein](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8805120)</sub>

The "1400 g" is younger (on average) group; a closer estimate for his age range is less (but still more than 1230 g):

> Our control mean of 1400 g is similar to values of other studies of large groups of white men of similar age range (30–70 years)—eg, mean fresh brain weight=1399 g, n=1433, mean age=53 years.<sup>[20](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/727739)</sup> For the age-matched subgroup, mean (SD) fresh brain weight was 1386 g (149). In a large study, mean fresh brain weight for a 70–80 year age group was 1342 g, n=253.<sup>[20](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/727739)</sup>
>   <sub>[The exceptional brain of Albert Einstein](http://penthai.sc.mahidol.ac.th/html/articles/newsletter/paper3.pdf)</sub>